# Yammer URL Mobile Deep Links for iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, mobile, deep-linking, yammer

I have web page that contain Yammer URL (https://www.yammer.com/xx.com/home). I want all user to open Yammer app in their mobile phone when click that link. I followed the guide in https://developer.yammer.com/docs/ios-and-android but still no luck. How to make URL that automatically open Yammer mobile app when clicked or open store if user don't have Yammer mobile app?

Comment: I tried deep link https://developer.yammer.com/docs/ios-and-android and it automatically open Yammer app, but it will open browser if user don't have Yammer app. How to make it open store (play store/app store) so user can install Yammer app?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like if you add the query string parameter "allow_app_redirect=1" it will allow the Yammer app to be opened directly.

Example:
https://www.yammer.com/contoso.com/threads/839670942?allow_app_redirect=1